# Percentage of Running Totals

Tags: crystal-reports

I am needing to show the ratio of one running total over the grand total (which is also a running total). The issue is that the grand total is not fully evaluated until the end of the group, so the percentages are thrown off. For example, I need to evaluate P (and F is the result of a complex formula):

```
GT = A1+A2+A3
    A1=F1+F2+F3    P1=A1/GT
        F1
        F2
        F3
    A2=F1+F2+F3    P2=A2/GT
        F1
        F2
        F3
    A3=F1+F2+F3    P3=A3/GT
        F1
        F2
        F3
```

The issue is that you cannot use the Summary function for A because Summary won't work with formulas like F. Therefore, A is a custom three-part running total (initialize, increment, total) in the form of a forumla. For the same reason, it seems that GT also must be a three-part running total formula.

As I mentioned earlier, this causes P to evaluate when GT has not been fully calculated. Is there any way to evaluate P after GT is fully evaluated? Or should I be going about this a different way?

**In response to cojimarmiami, each F is a formula that conditionally sums the details below it. The details sometimes include duplicate values and sometimes include null values. F needs to show the sum of each distinct record, therefore F is:

```
IF distinctcount(d,F)=0 and distinctcount(e,F)=0
THEN 0
ELSEIF distinctcount(d,F)=0
THEN sum(e,F)/distinct count(e,F)
ELSEIF distinctcount(e,F)=0
THEN sum(d,F)/distinct count(d,F)
ELSE sum(d,F)/distinct count(d,F) + sum(e,F)/distinct count(e,F)
```

where d and e are details contained within F's group.

Comment: could you please post F1,F2 and F3 formulas code?

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Comment: what is the purpose of using the running total? have you tried general summarization process?

Comment: as Siva said, have you tried general summarization using distinct count?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, the Summary function isn't available with certain formulas. Apparently A and F cannot be summarized with this function.